# Perl6 split function adding extra elements to array

Tags: raku

```
my @r = split("", "hi");
say @r.elems;
--> output: 4
```

`split` is adding two extra elements to the array, one at the beginning and another at the end.

I have to do shift and pop after every split to correct for this.

Is there a better way to split a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're splitting on the empty string, you *will* get an empty element at the start and the end of the returned list as there is also an empty string before and after the string.

What you want is `.comb` without parameters, written out completely functionally:

```
"hi".comb.elems.say;    # 2
```

See https://docs.raku.org/routine/comb#(Str)_routine_comb for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is when you use an empty Str `“”` for the delimiter it is the same as if you had used the regex `/<|wb>/` which matches next to characters. So it also matches before the first character, and after the last character. Perl 5 removes these “extra” strings for you in this case (and in this case only), which is likely where the confusion lays.

What Perl 6 does instead is allow you to explicitly `:skip-empty` values

```perl6
'hi'.split('') :skip-empty
'hi'.split('', :skip-empty)

split("", "hi") :skip-empty
split("", "hi", :skip-empty)
```

Or to specify what you actually want

```perl6
'hi'.comb( /./ )
'hi'.comb( 1 )
'hi'.comb

comb( /./, 'hi' )
comb(   1, 'hi' )
```